# Have a VBA macro run for all tables under each section

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an MS Word macro, that does a merge of all the tables in the document, besides the first one.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
    For i = .Tables.Count To 3 Step -1
        Set rng = .Tables(i).Range
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        rng.Start = .Tables(i - 1).Range.End
        rng.Delete
    Next i
End With
```

Now instead of it running over all tables I'd like it to run over all tables under each section heading. How would this be possible?

Alternatively, instead of `ActiveDocument` use `Selection` and keep selecting a whole section, one after another.

Comment: Used a work-around, by giving always the first table in the section a title and then check before merging if the title matches. This way, it can stay `With ActiveDocument`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to look into `StoryRanges` [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845743%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

This link [CLICK HERE](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm) has some great resources on looping through different `StoryRanges` for the purposes of doing a `Find` and `Replace` but you could remove that code and use your own code in its place.